# Sqlite db size did not change?

Tags: android, sqlite

I delete some records from my db file using sqlitespy, but db size is always 216064. I'm very confused. What's wrong? thank you.

EDIT:

```
is = context.getAssets().open(ASSETS_URI);
if (!(new File(DB_URI).length() != is.available()) {
  new File(DB_URI).delete;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is wrong.

Deleted data can result in empty pages in the database file. You need to [`VACUUM`](http://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) to get rid of the unused pages, or set the database to [`auto_vacuum`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum).

Further reading about the file format: http://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html

Comment: So how to determine if sqlite file is changed between /assets/a1.db and  /data/data/a2.db in android?

Comment: For what purpose? It's your database so you know when your code is writing to it, and you only need a dataabse from assets when setting up the initial version of the database file.

Comment: Use database version numbers (`getVersion()`) for that. https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper makes it much easier.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I want.